# MongoDB Group by field, count it and sort it desc

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document structure:

```
{
    ..
    "mainsubject" : {
        "code": 2768,
        "name": "Abc"
    }
}
```

Now I need a list of all mainsubject.code's and how often they are used.

In SQL i would do something like this:

```
SELECT mainsubject_code, COUNT(*) AS 'count'
FROM products
GROUP BY mainsubject_code
ORDER BY count
```

I already was able to group it and count it:

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:"$mainsubject.code", count:{$sum:1}}}
]);
```

But how to sort it?

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  {
     $group: { 
        _id: "$mainsubject.code", 
        countA: { $sum: 1}
     }
  },
  {
    $sort:{$mainsubject.code:1}
  }
])
```

did not work?

Comment: after grouping, your document structure change. The field "mainsubject.code" no longer exists, and is replaced by "_id". Try adding this **`$sort`** stage instead: `{$sort: {_id: 1}}`

Comment: Think "pipline" like "pipe" `|` on the command line. On each separation the only "input" is the previous "output". Therefore only `_id` and `countA` are the properties after `$group`.

Comment: Ah. Ok! Now I understand. Its like using Subqueries on SQL or pipes on linux command line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On looking at your sql query, it looks like you want to sort by count. So in mongo query also you should mention `countA` as the sort field.

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  {
     $group: { 
        _id: "$mainsubject.code", 
        countA: { $sum: 1}
     }
  },
  {
    $sort:{'countA':1}
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to sort by `_id` field that is the name of the field resulting from the `$group` stage of your aggregation pipeline. So, modify your query in this way:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  {
     $group: { 
        _id: "$mainsubject.code", 
        countA: { $sum: 1}
     }
  },
  {
     $sort:{_id:1}
  }
])
```

In this way you're sorting by _id ascending. Your SQL equivalent query is actually sorting by `count` and to achieve this you can change the `$sort` stage to:

```
$sort:{"countA":1}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct as well, but I picked ankit's because his answer is just a little bit shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Use Sort By Count ($sortByCount)
Groups incoming documents based on the value of a specified expression, then computes the count of documents in each distinct group.

`db.coll.aggregate([ { $sortByCount: "$mainsubject.code" } ]`