# Mongo $group and $count, and then $sort the result

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple table with ranked users...

```
User:
{
    "_id" : "aaa",
    "rank" : 10
},
{
    "_id" : "bbb",
    "rank" : 30
},
{
    "_id" : "ccc",
    "rank" : 20
},
{
    "_id" : "ddd",
    "rank" : 30
},
{
    "_id" : "eee",
    "rank" : 30
},
{
    "_id" : "fff",
    "rank" : 10
}
```

And I would like to count how many have each rank, and then sort them with highest to lowest count
So I can get this result:

```
Result: 
{
        "rank" : 30,
        "count":  3
},
{
        "rank" : 10,
        "count":  2
},
{
        "rank" : 20,
        "count":  1
}
```

I tried different things but cant seem to get the correct output

```
db.getCollection("user").aggregate([
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "rank": "$rank"
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        },
        "$sort": {
            "count" : -1
    }
])
```

I hope this is possible to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB Group by field, count it and sort it desc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802035/mongodb-group-by-field-count-it-and-sort-it-desc)

Comment: I wish I had found that one before I asked. I found 20 others but none fit my need. Anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count and then sort them by aggregation in mongodb

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate(
  [
    {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$rank",
           count: { $sum: 1 }
         }
     },

    { $sort : { count : -1} }
  ]
)
```

Working example
https://mongoplayground.net/p/aM3Ci3GACjp

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add additional group or count stages when you can do it in one go -

```
db.getCollection("user").aggregate([
    {
       $sortByCount: "$rank"
    }
])
```