# Mongo count total of each type

Tags: mongodb

I've got a Mongo collection that has documents that looks like:

- student_id
- class_number
- ...

I wanna get the total number of students that belongs to each `class_number` ordered with the class with most students at the top

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: tried to group the results by the class_number but I'm kinda new to Mongo :/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I advise you to read the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB Group by field, count it and sort it desc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802035/mongodb-group-by-field-count-it-and-sort-it-desc)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
db.col.aggregate([  {$group:{ _id:"$class_number" , count:{$sum:1} }}  , {$sort:{count:-1}}     ])
```

Comment: this is common question there are lots of questions like this, instead of answering we should consider to close this question.

Comment: @turvishal: Is there option to mark them similar with already answered ?

Comment: you have not enough privilege to close vote [see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), it requires 3000 reputations.it is ok no problem. but when you answer just make sure is there any similar questions then ask user in comment to does that answer his question.

Comment: if you want to see similar questions look at the right side panel in this page, titled as *Related* below ads you will see list of similar questions.

Comment: @turvishal: Thanks!