# MongoDB how to remove duplicates on aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to select all distinct values by aggregation in NodeJS.
For example i have the following documents in my collection:

```
{ city: 'Berlin', date: '12.12.2020' },
{ city: 'London', date: '11.12.2020' },
{ city: 'Berlin', date: '10.12.2020' },
{ city: 'Paris', date: '09.12.2020' },
{ city: 'Barcelona', date: '08.12.2020' },
{ city: 'Rome', date: '07.12.2020' },
{ city: 'Moscow', date: '06.12.2020' }
```

The result should be a list of the last 3 visited cities (different cities).

To be clear, I like to get a similar query as this one:

```
SELECT * FROM visits GROUP BY city ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3;
```

The expected result should looks like that:

```
{ city: 'Berlin', date: '12.12.2020' },
{ city: 'London', date: '11.12.2020' },
{ city: 'Paris', date: '09.12.2020' }
```

What I did? Just the basic query:

```
mongodb.collection('visits').aggregate([ ..., { $limit: 3 }]);
```

Which statement do I need to achieve this result?

Comment: Date values should be **never** stored as strings, it's a design flaw. Use proper `Date` objects. How do you think sorting will work? "10.01.2021" would come before "13.01.1900"

Comment: Which date do you like to get? For example for "Berlin" you have "12.12.2020" and "10.12.2020"

Comment: look at the similar question [MongoDB Group by field, count it and sort it desc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802035/mongodb-group-by-field-count-it-and-sort-it-desc), you just need to add limit stage at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$group` statement:

```js
mongodb.collection('visits').aggregate([
    {
        $sort: {
            date: -1
        } 
    },
    { 
        $group: {
            _id: $city,
            date: { $first: $date }
        }
    }, 
    {
        $project: {
            city: $city,
            date: $date,
            _id: 0
        }
    },
    { 
        $limit: 3 
    }
]);
```

PS: You should use the correct `Date` mongodb object for sorting to work properly

Comment: i removed the project part and used $group: { _id: { city: '$city' } }, then it worked. for the date i use mongodb db date object, but i didn't want to us this long format in my example :). thank you anyway

Comment: Sort order should be `1` or `-1` rather than "DESC"/"ASC" And values need to be quoted.